# Xamarin NLog Android Eventlogging

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, nlog

Can someone explain me how to create an `eventlogger` with **NLog** for **Android** in **Xamarin C#**?

My **NLog** config:

```xml
<target xsi:type="EventLog"
          name="String"
          layout="Layout"
          machineName="String"
          source="Layout"
          category="Layout"
          eventId="Layout"
          log="String" />

<rules>
   <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="String" />
</rules
```

I want to have a separate class which I can call to start tracking every action of the user in the app. It should write everything in a txt-file that can be sent. I still can´t figure out how to get the data and how to send the file for example to an **IIS-Server**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eventlog target isn't available on Android, as the event log is a Windows-only. (See also [NLog platform support](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/platform-support)

To send logs from your Android to a Server, you could use the Network or Webservice target. See [target list](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Targets)